# Create-react-app installation not completing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Good day fellas.

Please I need your solution for my current challenge I'm facing. I have been trying to set a SPA using create-react-app but I keep on getting the "template not found" error message. I have tried all the solutions and quick fixes I saw here and I'm still getting the error.

Please what's the solution for this problem?

I uninstalled Create-react-app globally, cleared cache and other things but none seems to working

Comment: Can you edit your post and add a screenshot? Also, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your information is not sufficient to understand error. If you want to use CRA then you can follow this link [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app). CRA is built on Webpack bundle.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

You can use Vitejs to create a react app. It is pretty easy and fast with good community support [create-vite-project](https://vitejs.dev/guide/)

Make sure you have compatible version of node and npm. For example i am using

```
Node version : v16.16.0
Npm version : 8.11.0
```

You can install node version according to your need from nvm.

- For installing on ubuntu you can follow this URL
  https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating
- For installing on window
  https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases